# Find row Index of strings in cell Array (Matlab)

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell-array

If I have a cell array `C`:

```
C =  {'name'  'hh' '23' []     []
    'last'  'bb' '12' '8'    'hello'
    'In'    'kk' '12' '2131' []
    'name'  'kk' '23' []     []
    'name'  'cv' '22' []     []
    'name'  'ph' '23' []     [] } ;
```

How can I get the row index of all the rows that have **'name'** in the first column and **'23'** in the third column?

```
indexresult = [1,4,6]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The simplest way to do this** (all-versions compatible) would be to just use [`strcmp`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html), which can accept cell arrays and does a "string compare".

**One liner**

```
indexresult = find(strcmp(C(:,1), 'name') & strcmp(C(:,3), '23'));
% indexresult = [1; 4; 6];
```

**Explanation**

```
% Get logical array of rows where first column is 'name'
logicalname = strcmp(C(:,1), 'name');
% Get logical array of rows where third column is '23'
logical23 = strcmp(C(:,3), '23');
% Get logical array where both of the above are true, using and (&)
logicalname23 = strcmp(C(:,1), 'name') & strcmp(C(:,3), '23');
% Get indices from logical array using find
indexresult = find(strcmp(C(:,1), 'name') & strcmp(C(:,3), '23'));
% If you wanted a row vector instead of column vector, just transpose too
indexresult = find(strcmp(C(:,1), 'name') & strcmp(C(:,3), '23')).';
```

---

If you want to be case insensitive (matching `'name', 'NAME', 'Name', ...`) then use `strcmpi` instead of `strcmp`.

Answer (score -1):

YOu can use *strfind* to get the indices which has string name and then use logical indices to get 23 out of the obtained indices.

```
C =  {'name'  'hh' '23' []     []
   'last'  'bb' '12' '8'    'hello'
   'In'    'kk' '12' '2131' []
   'name'  'kk' '23' []     []
   'name'  'cv' '22' []     []
   'name'  'ph' '23' []     [] } ;

% find indices of name
idx = strfind(C(:,1), 'name');
idx = find(not(cellfun('isempty', idx)));
% pick 23 from 3rc column

iwant =idx((str2double(C(idx,3))==23))
```

Comment: Be aware that `strfind` will also match any strings which *contain* `'name'`, such as `'name1234'`